# Any idea to make my html page look better?

Tags: html, css

I create a web page to control my TV (See the figure below). When I click the button, the server receives the POST request and translates it to IR signals.

It works. But the UI looks ugly. I'm newbie of the web front-end. Is there any CSS library can make the buttons look better, or and some dynamic appearance with JS library?

BTW, the web server is hosted on Arduino, which has 2K memory, 16MHz CPU and 30k flash. So there isn't enough memory to save the internal CSS. I want the html page as small as possible. What I'm looking for is the CSS which I can link.

[image: TV controller]

**UPDATE 7/23/2012**

I add the CSS code below and the buttons look letter, though it is not perfect enough.

```
button {
            display: inline-block;
            background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#f1da36), color-stop(100%,#fcf088));
            background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top, #f1da36 0%, #fcf088 100%);
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #777777, 0px 0px 2px #333333 inset;
            -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #777777, 0px 0px 2px #333333 inset;
            box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #777777, 0px 0px 2px #333333 inset;
            -webkit-border-radius: 30px;
            -moz-border-radius: 30px;
            border-radius: 30px;
            padding: 10px 15px;
            border-color: #ffffff;
            border-width: 1px;
            border-style: solid;
            font-size: 16px;
            color: #000000;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
        button:hover {
            background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#eeff07), color-stop(100%,#fcf088));
            background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top, #eeff07 0%, #fcf088 100%);
        }
        button:active {
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #333333 inset;
            -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #333333 inset;
            box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #333333 inset;
        }
```

[image: IR Design 2]

Comment: Look into twitter bootstrap. Not sure if there's a hosted version.

Comment: Hello bfavaretto, I can't access twitter in our country. Could you help to post a snapshot. Even though I can't read its source code, at least I can know what a better UI should be.

Comment: Bootstrap is a set of CSS and JavaScript components for websites, created by the guys from Twitter. They have very nice-looking buttons that require just a CSS file to be included in your HTML. Bootstrap is hosted on GitHub, I hope you can access it: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#buttons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just do styling with CSS and save it in another file. Then you could host the CSS file on a separate server and link it externally.

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.myotherserver.com/mystyle.css" />
</head>
```

If you don't have other hosting set up, you could theoretically host the file using dropbox or something similar.

http://www.maclife.com/article/howtos/how_host_your_website_dropbox

If you aren't looking to learn how to style CSS yourself, you can just copy something from a site like this, or generate it using one of the many generators out there.

http://www.cssbutton.me/

Comment: Thank you Bruce for your link. I find many awesome buttons from it. I'll have a try.

Answer (score 1):

What about using an [image of a remote control](http://www.google.com/imgres?q=tv%20remote%20psd&um=1&hl=en&client=safari&sa=N&rls=en&biw=1024&bih=712&tbm=isch&tbnid=HGCUJLDyM0MK9M%3a&imgrefurl=http://www.ugraphic.net/dl/old%2btelevision%2bpsd.html&docid=-VWdZL8DguxY3M&imgurl=http://3.s3.envato.com/files/30593592/Television_Remote.jpg&w=590&h=1180&ei=jh4MULS_McLs0gHXhu3zAw&zoom=1&iact=hc&vpx=513&vpy=148&dur=459&hovh=318&hovw=159&tx=102&ty=171&sig=111187523873639732758&page=2&tbnh=156&tbnw=77&start=12&ndsp=20&ved=1t:429,r:2,s:12,i:122), then working with the [HTML map tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp)'s **on click** event to trigger your code-behind? Although I strongly suggest you at least take a look into the [basics of CSS](http://www.w3schools.com/css/).

Comment: I know the basic syntax of CSS. And I can read the CCS code. If I use an image to show the control, I can get the click event of the whole image. How can I distinguish which button in clicked?

Comment: The HTML Map tag allows you to take an image (e.g. the remote control) and split it into multiple clickable areas (e.g. the power button, the number 1 etc...). If you take a look at the HTML map tag link above you can see a live example. The 'areas' tag has an [onclick event](http://www.codingforums.com/archive/index.php/t-20057.html) that can be triggered to discern which area on the image was clicked.